# Add file name to beginning and line break at the end of file

Tags: windows, batch, batch-file

I want to add file name to the beginning of every file and line break

(-------------------------------------------------------) --> like this

```
                                           --> empty line after line break
```

to every file with to extension of .cpp

This command will add file name to every line of file and combine those files into one output file.

```
findstr "^" *.cpp >C:\users\user\desktop\output.txt
```

Could you help me modify this command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try a `for` loop file by file (`*.cpp`) and print each Name and eXtension (`%%~nxi`) redirecting to your `output.txt` file, then add the line at the end of each looped file with `type “current file in loop + echo;`

```bat
@echo off

cd/d "D:\Full\Path\To\cpp\Files\Folder"

for %%i in (*.cpp)do >>"Output.txt" (
     set /p "'=%%~nxi" <nul & echo;
     type "%%~fi" & echo;
    )
```

---

**Additional resources:**

- [`For /?`](https://ss64.com/nt/for.html)
- [Redirection](https://www.robvanderwoude.com/redirection.php)

  - `|`, `<`, `>`, `2>`, etc.

Comment: thanks, this works

Comment: Good to know! Thanks